# styling nested tags does not work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have the following code in html:

```
<div class="carousel-content">
    <div>
        <h2 class="hidden-sm contents">test<br> 
            test2
        </h2>
        <h3 class="visible-sm contents">test
        </h3>    
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have styled h2, and h3 like the following :

```
.carousel-content>div> h2,h3,h4{

    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 145%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;

}
```

but the styles do not apply. Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add full path for each of `h2, h3, h4` selectors:

```css
.carousel-content > div > h2,
.carousel-content > div > h3,
.carousel-content > div > h4 {

    color: red;
    line-height: 145%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;

}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-content">
    <div>
        <h2 class="hidden-sm contents">test<br> 
            test2
        </h2>
        <h3 class="visible-sm contents">test
        </h3>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx. But in my code, I needed to add div at the beginning to : div.carousel-content > div > h2,.....

Comment: Well sounds like you just needed more specific selector (by adding the `div` in the beginning it will be more specific so it will have higher priority when computing the final style set)